# Is there a way to create and modify HTML and Javascript files dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a project whose requirements have been consistently expanding. At first, it was fine because I could hard code most of it. However, I find that I am making different versions of the same type of forms and programming specific JS files to go along with them. Is there a way to dynamically create an HTML and JS file? So, maybe I could write a function or something that reads requirements from a text files, and from that, build an HTML file, a JavaScript file, and modify other JavaScript files within the directory. For example:

Say I have a JS file named main.js

```
   /* I hold all the basic requirements and functions for every form*/
   var blueForm = ...
   var redForm = ...
```

There currently exists HTML files named blueForm.html and redForm.html.
I want to add a function to main.js such that:

```
   function createNewForm(requirements){
        . . .
        createHTML();
        createJS();
        modifyMain(this); /* as in this file (main.js) */
        . . .
        if(successful){ return 0; }
        return 1;
   }
```

Now main.js should have been modified like:

```
   var blueForm = ...
   var redForm = ...
   var greenForm = ...
```

And now there exists HTML files named blueForm.html, redForm.html, and greenForm.html.

Comment: yes, you can totally generate html on the fly. This is how web works for the last 15 years or more. Dynamically generating JS is possible too (it is not any different from html in this regard), but perhaps it is better to write one copy of generic logic that will handle all forms.

Comment: I think most people would do this by creating content dynamically at the client instead of creating new static files at the server.

Comment: If you are going to build dynamic web pages I recommend looking in to server side solutions, like ASP.NET, PHP, NODE.JS etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes.  The most accessible way of doing this is using php, most commonly implemented through a Linux / Apache / MySQL / PHP stack (LAMP).  HTML and JS be easily injected into a file your browser reads as html.

Here's a sample.php file:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
    echo "Hello World";
    echo "<script>";
    $myvar = 1;
    if ($myvar==1) {
        echo "function dosomethingjavascripty() {";
        echo "console.log('doing it');";
        echo "}";
    }
    echo "</script>";
?>
</html>
</body>
```

Comment: Every high level language can do this: python, ruby, perl, go... Just to know, `$myvar=1` is a security checking or what is it ?

Comment: Nothing specific, meant as an abstract placeholder.